# ImageDataGenerator gives different result than cv2

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have been trying to create a neural network architecture that recognizes traffic signs. I am using the German Traffic Signs dataset and is composed of 43 classes. First of all, if I get the data by using cv2 and stack them into an array, then DNN works perfectly! I get %99 accuracy and tiny loss.

[image: Getting data by cv2]

On the other hand, I want to use ImageDataGenerator. I haven't changed a thing. As far as I know, I should be able to get the same result, yet I get 0.05-ish accuracy and 3.5-ish loss constantly.

[image: Getting data by ImageDataGenerator]

This is the Neural Network Architecture I am using:

```
layers = [
tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(30, 30, 3)),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (7, 7), strides=2, padding="SAME"),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME"),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="SAME"),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(43, activation="softmax"),
]
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(layers=layers)
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])
```

Thanks!

[EDIT]:
I've changed my optimizer and surprisingly accuracy is increasing, but validation accuracy is still 0.04.

```
lr = 0.01
sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, 
                              decay=1e-6, 
                              momentum=0.9, 
                              nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, 
              loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              metrics= ["acc"])
```

Comment: please show your code for model.fit. Also  for validation_generator in flow_from_directory set shuffle=False

Comment: I am too ashamed that I've asked a question like this... The whole time I've been thinking that Shuffle is a parameter of ImageDataGenerator, not its object's. Thank you @GerryP . Enlightened me :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer here from the comment section for the benefit of the community.

The default parameter of [flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) for shuffle will be set to `True`, by changing it to `False` for `validation_generator` has resolved the issue.